# Replicate each row and change one column into binary values

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(n = c(3, 2, 2), 
                 survive = c(2, 1, 2), 
                 a = c(1,1,0), 
                 b = c(0,0,1))
```

How can I expand the last two columns of the data.frame above, so that each row appears the number of times specified in the column 'n'. And the second column "survive" changes into binary values 0/1 according to the value of "survive"

In other words:

```
n  survive a  b
3  2       1  0
2  1       1  0
2  2       0  1
```

To this

```
survive a  b
1       1  0
1       1  0
0       1  0
1       1  0
0       1  0
1       0  1
1       0  1
```

Comment: @Sotos It was not my dupe, somebody else commented it

Comment: the example data is different from what's in the codeblock.

Comment: @Sotos I reopened it.  I thought it was based on replication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several alternative solutions:

**1)** Using base R:

```
rn <- rep(1:nrow(df), df$n)
df2 <- df[rn,]
df2$survive <- as.integer(df2$survive >= ave(rn, rn, FUN = seq_along))
```

which gives:

```
> df2[,-1]
   survive a b
1:       1 1 0
2:       1 1 0
3:       0 1 0
4:       1 1 0
5:       0 1 0
6:       1 0 1
7:       1 0 1
```

---

**2)** Using the *data.table*-package:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- setDT(df)[, rid := .I
                 ][, .(survive = c(rep(1, survive), rep(0, n - survive)), a, b)
                   , by = rid
                   ][, rid := NULL][]
```

which gives:

```
> df2
   survive a b
1:       1 1 0
2:       1 1 0
3:       0 1 0
4:       1 1 0
5:       0 1 0
6:       1 0 1
7:       1 0 1
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
df2 <- setDT(df)[, .(survive = c(rep(1, survive), rep(0, n - survive)), a, b), by = 1:nrow(df)
                 ][, nrow := NULL]
```

---

**3)** Using the *dplyr*-package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(rid = row_number()) %>% 
  .[rep(1:nrow(df), df$n),] %>% 
  group_by(rid) %>% 
  mutate(survive = c(rep(1, unique(survive)), rep(0, unique(n) - unique(survive))) ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-n, -rid)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  survive     a     b
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     1     0
2       1     1     0
3       0     1     0
4       1     1     0
5       0     1     0
6       1     0     1
7       1     0     1
```

---

**Used data:**

```
df <- data.frame(n = c(3, 2, 2), 
                 survive = c(2, 1, 2), 
                 a = c(1,1,0), 
                 b = c(0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution using `splitstackshape` to expand rows and `dplyr`,

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = 1) %>% 
  expandRows('n') %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(survive) != 0))) %>% 
  mutate(survive = replace(new, tail(new, n() - survive[1]), 0)) %>% 
  arrange(grp, desc(survive)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(new, grp))

# A tibble: 7 × 3
#  survive     a     b
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1       1     1     0
#2       1     1     0
#3       0     1     0
#4       1     1     0
#5       0     1     0
#6       1     0     1
#7       1     0     1
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do with `base R`

```
df2 <- df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), df1$n),-(1:2)]
row.names(df2) <- NULL
df2 <- cbind(Survive = unlist(Map(function(x, y) rep(c(1,0),
             c(y, x-y)),  df1$n, df1$survive)), df2)
df2
#  Survive a b
#1       1 1 0
#2       1 1 0
#3       0 1 0
#4       1 1 0
#5       0 1 0
#6       1 0 1
#7       1 0 1
```

---

Or a more vectorized approach is

```
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$n),-(1:2)]
df1$survive <- with(df, rep(rep(c(1,0), nrow(df)), rbind(survive, n - survive)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a split/apply/combine approach in base R:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, seq_along(df$n)), function(i) {

  survive = c(rep(1, i$survive), rep(0, i$n - i$survive))

  cbind(survive, i[rep(1, i$n), c("a", "b")])

}))
```

Result:

```
      survive a b
1.1         1 1 0
1.1.1       1 1 0
1.1.2       0 1 0
2.2         1 1 0
2.2.1       0 1 0
3.3         1 0 1
3.3.1       1 0 1
```